Change dot color selection field

My objective is to add a new state_selection widget (in the same way as the one that is present in the Kanban view of the tasks of the project module) with three (3) options / colors :

gray
Orange
Red

I mean, I want the new state to have a new color, for example, orange.
Preferably, I would like to do it myself if it is not too complicated; otherwise, an existing module will do the trick.
I have no idea how to do it, and I can't find any documentation on it. Can you help me or indicate a module to do this simply?
this is the xml code
<xpath expr="//field[@name='kanban_state']" position="replace">
                <field name="kanban_state_child" widget="state_selection"/>
</xpath> 

and this is the field definition
kanban_state_child = fields.Selection([
        ('on_hold', 'En attente'),
        ('normal', 'En cours'),
        ('done', 'Prêt'),
        ('blocked', 'Bloquée')], string='Status',
        copy=False, default='on_hold', required=True, readonly=False, store=True)


Your question is lacking a [mre] of what you already have

The widget are just controls (buttons) and three color are chosen.  the colors picked can be picked from the standard colors or any of your own colors from rgb

i've updated my question @mozway

how to do it @jdweng

See https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-add-a-create-button-near-tree-and-kanban-view-in-odoo-16

it's not what i want , i'll add a picture to my post to explain what i want

You can extend the selection state widget
JS:
  /** @odoo-module */
  
  import { registry } from '@web/core/registry';
  import { StateSelectionField } from '@web/views/fields/state_selection/state_selection_field';

  
  export class CustomStateSelectionField extends StateSelectionField {
      setup() {
         super.setup();
         this.colors = {
            normal: "orange",
            done: "green",
            blocked: "red",
        };
     }

     get showLabel() {
        return true;
    }
 }
 
 registry.category('fields').add('custom_state_selection', CustomStateSelectionField);

SCSS:
.o_status {
     @extend .o_status;
     &.o_status_orange {
         @extend .bg-warning;
    }
}

Add the fiels under assets entry in the __manifest__.py file:
'assets': {
    'web.assets_backend': [
        "MODULE_NAME/static/src/js/state_selection.js",
        "MODULE_NAME/static/src/scss/state_selection.scss",
    ],
},

And set the widget attribute of the selection field to custom_state_selection

that worked perfectly thank you so much
